# Getting Cell ID on Android Tablet with Data Connection

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellid

I've tried to follow numerous posts without much success. Namely, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576701/android-get-cellid-and-rss-for-base-station-and-neigboring-cells) sums up both the new way (after API 17) as well as old way to get CID. I've also tried

```
CdmaCellLocation cdmaLocation = (CdmaCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
```

which returns null even though I am connected to the Verizon network. although in the docs:

```
If there is only one radio in the device and that radio has an LTE connection, this method will return null. 
The implementation must not to try add LTE identifiers into the existing cdma/gsm classes.
```

looking further into the problem, I tried telephonyManager.getPhoneType() and got 0, which means it's not recognized as a CDMA or GSM phone despite the fact that it has data connection. Is there a way to work around this to get the CID somehow before API 17? The actual tablet I am working with is the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Thanks